# Postback and URL Rewriter

Tags: c#, asp.net-membership, urlrewriter

I have an interesting problem where I have hit a brick wall.  I have an issue with a login page which implements forms authentication and uses Intellegencia.Rewriter.  The authentication works fine on localhost for all browsers, but on the server it appears that the postback nature of the page is lost in IE9, yet works fine in Chrome. The code I have on the Login page is:

```
bool isAuthenticated = Membership.ValidateUser(username, password);
        string returnUrl = Server.HtmlDecode(Request["ReturnUrl"]);
        lblLoggedIn.Text = Page.IsPostBack.ToString();
        if (isAuthenticated && 
                            Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name == "")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.User = AuthenticateUserIfValid(username);
                Thread.CurrentPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User;
            }
```

Where the Function AuthenticateUserIfValid is:

```
public Principal.GenericPrincipal AuthenticateUserIfValid(string username)
{
    MembershipUser mpc = Membership.FindUsersByName(username)[username];
    string[] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(mpc.UserName);
    string strRoles = "";

    foreach (string role in roles) 
                   strRoles += strRoles != "" ? "," + role : role;

    FormsAuthenticationTicket fat = 
                    new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, mpc.UserName.ToString(),
                 DateTime.Now, 
                           DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), 
                           true, 
                           strRoles, 
                           FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

    Response.Cookies.Add(
                        new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
                   FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(fat)));

    Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("UserRoles", strRoles));

    Principal.GenericPrincipal myPrincipal;
    Principal.GenericIdentity myIdentity = 
                     new Principal.GenericIdentity(mpc.UserName);
    myPrincipal = new Principal.GenericPrincipal(myIdentity, roles);
    return myPrincipal;

}
```

Any thoughts or solutions would be most appreciated.  Regards,

MD